# CMD variable does not change

Tags: batch-file, cmd, zip

I am writing my first little cmd script right now but I have a problem.
But first things first:

```
pushd Z:\customScripts
echo %filename%
set /p filename=Enter filename please: && 7za.exe a -tzip Z:\customScripts\"%filename%".zip "%filename%".py license.txt
```

I just started cmd and I only wanted to do this script to help me a little bit
7za makes a zip file out of my specified file.

Example Case:
I open a fresh CMD window. The first time I run my code and my input is `"helloWorld"`(and my directory has a file called, `"helloWorld.py"`)
It creates a zip file called "%filename%.zip" and it contains only the license.txt nothing else.
But the second time I run it(with the same still opened CMD window), it does not matter what my input is, it remembers the defined variable %filename% from the last time and create the right zip file with the right name and content....

I want that my input defines the name of the zip file and it should zip the license.txt and the python script with my input as a name.
I save my file as .bat if it makes any difference.
I hope I made my problem clear and some can help me!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUpPN.png)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are after.  With no input, just enter, the previous value persists. The conditional execution `&&` will IMO always be true when not breaking the batch. You should check if filename is defined and the existence of "%filenam%.py" also your quoting is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have fallen afoul of two characteristics of batch.

The first is that unless you start your batch with

```
@echo off
setlocal
```

then any values that you set in any run for any particular instance of a `cmd` window  remain set for that command window instance.

The `@echo off` is merely the common starting instruction which turns command-echoing `off`. Command-echoing (where the command is echoed to the console before execution) is the standard mode. It may be left or turned `on` for debugging purposes, but normally you don't want to see the step-by-step instructions.

The `setlocal` command establishes a *local environment* (it also has other uses, but please try to walk before you run...) so that any variable that is added/deleted/changed *within* a batch is restored to its starting value when the batch ends (or an `endlocal` command is executed). In this way, you can keep the environment "clean" so that successive batches do not clutter the environment with additions, deletions and changes.

The second is an instance related to `delayed expansion` (there are many SO articles on this matter - use the `search` facility).

Batch parses source lines logical-line by logical-line. A logical line is one physical line or more than one physical line over which a command or command-sequence is parenthesised.

The first step in this parsing is to replace any `%var%` with the *actual value* of `var` at that time.

Consequently, your

```
set /p filename=Enter filename please: && 7za.exe a -tzip Z:\customScripts\"%filename%".zip "%filename%".py license.txt
```

since it is a single *logical* line will  first substitute for `%filename% (which will be the value established in the *last* run as your code stands) and then execute the`set /p`and if setting the variable is successful then execute the`7a`command into which the value of`filename` has already been substituted.

To fix:

```
@echo off
setlocal

pushd Z:\customScripts
echo %filename%
set /p filename=Enter filename please: 
if defined filename 7za.exe a -tzip Z:\customScripts\"%filename%".zip "%filename%".py license.txt

popd
```

Another strange characteristic of `set /p` is that if you respond simply <kbd>enter</kbd> the the value in the target variable will not be *empty* but *unchanged*.

I suspect this is actually part of a larger script, but I've applied the closing `popd` for the sake of completeness.

---

Verbatim test code:

```dos
ECHO ------------- START AT %time%
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

pushd %sourcedir%
echo %filename%
set /p filename=Enter filename please: 
if defined filename c:\portable\PortableApps\PortableApps.com\App\7-Zip\7za.exe a -tzip %sourcedir%\"%filename%".zip "%filename%".py license.txt
DIR /a-d
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

Results:

```
------------- START AT  1:52:17.58
ECHO is off.
Enter filename please: q50666890

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive U:\sourcedir\q50666890.zip

Compressing  license.txt
Compressing  q50666890.py

Everything is Ok
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C653-9000

 Directory of U:\sourcedir

04/06/2018  01:52           141,778 q50666890.py
04/06/2018  01:52           150,829 license.txt
04/06/2018  01:52            64,954 q50666890.zip
```

which is precisely what I expected.

Notes : - `U:\sourcedir` is my testing directory

My copy of `7za` is located as indicated

`q50666890` is this question number on SO so I can refer back to it and its testfiles easily.

Comment: I does not work as expected
With your code it does not ask me for input, it just does nothing

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe the way I try to run the code is false?
I just copy the whole thing, paste it into my cmd window and press enter?
or should I save it and run or something like this?

Comment: Man, thats kinda embarrassing, saving as .cmd or .bat made it work.... Now it works thanks both, huge help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Changed quoting and tested locally with 7z.exe without problem.

```
:: SO_50666890.cmd
@Echo off
Set "BaseFolder=Z:\customScripts\"

Pushd "%BaseFolder%" 
Set "filename="
set /p "filename=Enter filename please: "
if not defined filename exit /B 0
If exist "%filename%.py" (
  7z.exe a -tzip "%BaseFolder%%filename%.zip" "%filename%.py" license.txt
) else (
  Echo file : %filename%.py doesn't exist
)
```

Comment: my console is asking for "More?" at the line with the 7za.exe

Comment: See  slightly changed answer. Works here wihtout problem.

Comment: I added a screenshot ^

Comment: does it make a difference that I copy and paste it into cmd?

Comment: Yes, code for cmd line is different. Please save the code in a file name of your choice and the extension `.cmd` or `.bat`

Comment: Man, thats kinda embarrassing....
Now it works thanks both, huge help! :)